# How do i show information which i have saved in an Array?

Tags: java

i am very very new into Java and i have a project which is due soon.

I have done everything else other than to store and display information in the work.

How do i do that?

Firstly, i have 4 classes

Number 1 is the  class which is named " Computer " . It stores all the variables.

```
public class Computer {
private String computerID;
private String processorSpeed;
private String ram;
private String hardDisk;
public double price;

 public Computer(String computerID,String processorSpeed,String ram,String hardDisk){

    this.computerID = computerID;
    this.processorSpeed = processorSpeed;
    this.ram = ram;
    this.hardDisk = hardDisk;

     }//Constructor

public String getComputerID(){
    return computerID;
}//getComputerID

public String getProcessorSpeed(){
    return processorSpeed;
}//getProcessorSpeed

public String getRam(){
    return ram;
}//getRam

public String getHardDisk(){
    return hardDisk;
}//getHardDisk

}//class Computer
```

Number 2 is the class which is named "Computer Demo" . It will display all the text that i have written, and is the main class. But i do not know where to put the for loop to display the stored information.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ComputerDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input  = new Scanner(System.in);

    String response;
    int countDesktop = 1;// d1
    int countdeskid = 1;//desktop ID
    int countdeskpspd = 1;// array deskpspd
    int countdeskram = 1;// dekstop ram
    int countdeskdisk = 1;// desktop disk
    int countdeskmonitor = 1;// desktop monitor

    Desktop[] d1 = new Desktop[countDesktop];

    int countLaptop = 1; // l1
    int countlaptopid = 1 ; // laptop ID
    int countlaptoppspd = 1 ; // array deskspspd
    int countlaptopram = 1 ; // laptop ram
    int countlaptopdisk = 1 ; // laptop disk
    int countlaptopweight = 1 ; // laptop weight

    Laptop[] l1 = new Laptop[countLaptop] ;

    String[] deskid = new String[countdeskid];
    String[] deskpspd = new String[countdeskpspd];
    String[] deskram = new String[countdeskram];
    String[] deskdisk = new String[countdeskdisk];
    String[] deskmonitor = new String[countdeskmonitor];

    do {
        System.out.println("************************ Artificial Intelligence Co. ************************");
        System.out.println("Computer Menu:");
        System.out.println("1. Add information for new Desktop");
        System.out.println("2. Add information for new Laptop");
        System.out.println("3. Display all computer information");
        System.out.println("4. Quit");
            System.out.println("*****************************************************************************");
        System.out.print("Please enter either 1 to 4: ");
        response = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("");
        try{
        if(Integer.parseInt(response) == (1)){

            System.out.println("=============================================================================================");
            System.out.println("Information for new Desktop");
            System.out.println("=============================================================================================");
            System.out.print("What is the computer ID : ");
            deskid[countdeskid-1] = input.nextLine();
            countdeskid++;
            System.out.print("What is the Processor Speed : ");
            deskpspd[countdeskpspd-1] = input.nextLine();
            countdeskpspd++;
            System.out.print("What is the RAM : ");
            deskram[countdeskram-1] = input.nextLine();
            countdeskram++;
            System.out.print("What is the Harddisk size : ");
            deskdisk[countdeskdisk-1] = input.nextLine();
            countdeskdisk++;
            System.out.print("What is the Monitor Type : ");
            deskmonitor[countdeskmonitor-1] = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("What is the Price : ");
            response = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Your information has  been added successfully.");
            System.out.println("");

    String[] laptopid = new String [countlaptopid] ;
    String[] laptoppspd = new String [countlaptoppspd] ;
    String[] laptopram = new String [countlaptopram] ;
    String[] laptopdisk = new String [countlaptopdisk] ;
    String[] laptopweight = new String [countlaptopweight] ;

        System.out.println("************************ Artificial Intelligence Co. ************************");
        System.out.println("Computer Menu:");
        System.out.println("1. Add information for new Desktop");
        System.out.println("2. Add information for new Laptop");
        System.out.println("3. Display all computer information");
        System.out.println("4. Quit");
        System.out.println("*****************************************************************************");
        System.out.print("Please enter either 1 to 4: ");
        response = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("");

        if(Integer.parseInt(response) == (2)){

            System.out.println("=============================================================================================");
            System.out.println("Information for new Laptop");
            System.out.println("=============================================================================================");
            System.out.print("What is the computer ID : ");
            laptopid[countlaptopid-1] = input.nextLine();
            countlaptopid++;
            System.out.print("What is the Processor Speed : ");
            laptoppspd[countlaptoppspd-1] = input.nextLine();
            countlaptoppspd++;
            System.out.print("What is the RAM : ");
            laptopram[countlaptopram-1] = input.nextLine();
            countlaptopram++;
            System.out.print("What is the Harddisk size : ");
            laptopdisk[countlaptopdisk-1] = input.nextLine();
            countlaptopdisk++;
            System.out.print("What is the weight : ");
            laptopweight[countlaptopweight-1] = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("What is the Price : ");
            response = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Your information has  been added successfully.");
            System.out.println("");

        }//else if 2
        else if(Integer.parseInt(response) == (3)){

        }//else if 3
        else if(Integer.parseInt(response) == (4)){
            break;
        }//else if 4

        }

          }//try
        catch(Exception e){

        }//catch

    }while(true);

}

}//class ComputerDemo
```

Last 2 is just a sub class which has extra information in it while it displays the code.

```
public class Desktop extends Computer {

String monitorType;

public Desktop(String monitor, String computerID,String processorSpeed,String ram,String hardDisk){
    super(computerID,processorSpeed,ram,hardDisk);
    this.monitorType = monitorType;
}//constructor

public void displayInfo(){

   System.out.println("Computer ID : " + getComputerID());
    System.out.println("Processor Speed : " + getProcessorSpeed());
    System.out.println("RAM : " + getRam());
    System.out.println("Harddisk : " + getHardDisk());
    System.out.println("Monitor : " + monitorType);
    System.out.println("Price : " + price);

}

}
```

and

```
public class Laptop extends Computer {

String weight;

public Laptop(String monitor, String computerID,String processorSpeed,String ram,String hardDisk){
    super(computerID,processorSpeed,ram,hardDisk);
    this.weight = weight;
}//constructor

public void displayInfo(){
    System.out.println("Computer ID : " + getComputerID());
    System.out.println("Processor Speed : " + getProcessorSpeed());
    System.out.println("RAM : " + getRam());
    System.out.println("Harddisk : " + getHardDisk());
    System.out.println("Weight : " + weight);
    System.out.println("Price : " + price);
       }

    } //Laptop
```

So how do i display the code using for loop? And where should i put the for loop in?

Comment: Where is the code? Read : [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Post the relevant part of the code you already have and explain your exact problems.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what the data is or what exactly you're trying to do, to display information in an array you would want to use a loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

EDIT:

First I'd change your information set up, since you have classes with constructors, fields, and methods that you're not using. After getting the information from the user, you should put that into your classes constructor then add the new object to an array. I.E.:

```
Laptop[] arrLaptop = new Laptop[count];
Laptop newLaptop = new Laptop(monitor, computerID, processorSpeed, ram, hardDisk);
arrLaptop[i] = newLaptop;
```

Then in your for loop you can run it like:

```
else if(Integer.parseInt(response) == (3)){
  for(int i = 0; i < arrLaptop.length; i++) {
    arrLaptop[i].displayInfo();
  }
}//else if 3
```

I recommend you take a look at some basic object oriented programming tutorials if you want a better understanding.

Comment: I'm trying to know where should i put the for code at. But i cant copy and paste my codes as it is quite long and the website do not allow me to.

Comment: You need to put four spaces before each line of code to make it a code block. Look at [Editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to see formatting information. As for where to put the for loop, it depends on your code.

Comment: Based on your program, obviously you'd want to add the for loop in your else if for the third option. I updated my answer with some information.

Comment: Where should i put the for loop in my else if ?

Comment: Where the response equals 3, like how I made my last code block.